# What's the relationship between the #mem_access and the #(sum of all kinds of cache hits and misses) in perf event report?

Tags: c++, linux, performance, caching, perf

I'm pretty confused about the Linux perf report of my program.
Below is the C++ source code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

#define THREAD_NUM 8
std::vector<double> tmp_sum(THREAD_NUM, 0);

void BadWorker(int idx, int min, int max) {
  for (int i = min; i <= max; ++i) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
      ++tmp_sum[idx];
    }
  }
}

void GoodWorker(int idx, int min, int max) {
  int tmp = 0;
  for (int i = min; i <= max; ++i) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
      ++tmp;
    }
  }
  tmp_sum[idx] = tmp;
}

int CountEvenConcurrentlyUsingBadWorker(int min, int max) {
  const int thread_num = THREAD_NUM;
  std::vector<std::thread> threads;
  for (int t = 0; t < thread_num; ++t) {
    int range = max / thread_num * (t + 1);
    threads.push_back(std::thread(BadWorker, t, min, range));
    min = range + 1;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < threads.size(); ++i) {
    threads[i].join();
  }

  int even = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < threads.size(); ++i) {
    even += tmp_sum[i];
  }

  return even;
}

int CountEvenConcurrentlyUsingGoodWorker(int min, int max) {
  const int thread_num = THREAD_NUM;
  std::vector<std::thread> threads;
  for (int t = 0; t < thread_num; ++t) {
    int range = max / thread_num * (t + 1);
    threads.push_back(std::thread(GoodWorker, t, min, range));
    min = range + 1;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < threads.size(); ++i) {
    threads[i].join();
  }

  int even = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < threads.size(); ++i) {
    even += tmp_sum[i];
  }

  return even;
}

int main() {
  constexpr int val = 20e8;
  // int bad_worker_res = CountEvenConcurrentlyUsingBadWorker(0, val);
  // std::cout << bad_worker_res << "\n";

  int good_worker_res = CountEvenConcurrentlyUsingGoodWorker(0, val);
  std::cout << good_worker_res << "\n";

  return 0;
}
```

First, I `disable the bad_worker and enable the good_worker` (as shown in the code already)

then I executed it with this command:
`g++ -g -std=c++14 -O2 no_false_sharing.cpp -o no_false_sharing -lpthread && sudo perf stat -e cpu-cycles,cache-misses,instructions,inst_spec,stalled-cycles-frontend,stalled-cycles-backend,L1-dcache-load-misses,L1-icache-load-misses,LLC-loads,LLC-load-misses,context-switches,branch-load-misses,branch-loads,mem_access,L1-dcache-loads,L1-icache-loads ./no_false_sharing`

and got the following result(several times, they are both similar):

[image]

I can explain most of the report but I am pretty confused about the number between the #mem_access and (#L1-dcache-loads and #L1-icache-loads).
In my opinion, all of the cache operations(including L1-dcache-loads, L1-icache-loads, LLC-loads, etc.) should be the subset of memory access(should it be the intention to access the memory?）. (Correct me if I'm wrong)
So in this case, how to explain the huge gap between #mem_access and the sum of (#L1-dcache-loads and #L1-icache-loads)?

CPU info:
Architecture: ARMV8

The CPU complex has up to 12 CPU cores.
Each core includes 64KB of Instruction L1 Cache and 64KB of Data Cache, and 256 KB of L2 Cache.
Each cluster also has 2MB L3 Cache.
The maximum supported CPU frequency 2.2 GHz.

OS info:
Linux ubuntu 5.10.65-tegra*emphasized text*

Also, you can see the perf report of the program if I `disable the good_worker and enable the bad_worker`(false sharing happens).
[image]

Comment: If you don't use so many events that it has to multiplex, is `mem_access` exactly the same as `L1-dcache-loads`? i.e. counting data loads but not stores?  And not counting instruction-fetch.  `perf` has to pick some HW event to map it to, and the `perf` developers may have been thinking differently from you about what it should mean, and/or the selection of possible events doesn't include loads+stores or data+instructions.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you so much. 
I just tried `-e L1-dcache-loads,mem_access` and got this result:
16910272      L1-dcache-loads
16912494      mem_access
(Sorry I have no idea how to format it here...)
I'm not sure if it means under armv8 architecture, `mem_access` only represents the intention to access `data` in memory only(excludes `instruction`).  Please correct me if I was wrong.

Comment: I'm not at all surprised that `mem_access` is only counting data accesses, not instruction-fetch.  That's kind of what I'd expect from that name. (Or the other possibility I might guess from that name is DRAM accesses or something, but clearly it's not that.)

Comment: It's very very common to separate data from instruction access, especially in a microarchitecture with split L1i and L1d cache.  Given the split caches, it barely makes sense to have one event that counts both.  You can manually add two separate hardware events if you want that, but normally you'd look for an L2 access event to count L1i L1d misses, rather than accesses, since that's what generates traffic at the inner-most unified level of cache (L2).